# Skinned verus Skunned

Tags: phrases

Grew up hearing my (partly Scottish) dad say "keep your eyes skunned" (my guess on how skunned is spelled) when looking for places or things as we drove down the road. I know of "eyes peeled". Came across a citation for "eyes skinned" elsewhere. My brothers and I have wondered the skunned origins, as our dad passed a few years ago.

Comment: I’m from Vermont and I grew up using the word skun or skunned for skinned

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "skunned" (instead of "skinned") is used in more than one place.

One source says that "skunned" is used in York County, PA:

> Today’s Yorkism comes courtesy of Pat Azriel of the York County Community Foundation.
>
> She says, “The latest I wanted to share with you happened a few weeks ago when someone was talking about how her son had hurt his knee while skateboarding; she used the word ‘skunned.’ When I asked about the word, she looked at me funny, and another person chimed in, ‘Yeah, you know, skinned, skanned, skunned.’ Not sure that there really is a ‘skanned’ but either way, ‘skunned’ is just bizarre!”
>   <sub>[Skinned, skanned, skunned: What happened to your knees?](http://www.yorkblog.com/onlyyork/2011/11/03/skinned-skanned-skunned-what-happened-to-your-knees/)</sub>

Another site indicates it's used in Carleton County, New Brunswick:

> **skun** \'skun\ v - The past tense of "skin"; [...] Sometimes also "skunned."
>   <sub>[Carleton County Colloquialisms: Skun](http://www.dooryard.ca/skun.html)</sub>

Yet another article, from an author who apparently lives in [Two Inlets](http://www.amythielen.com/the-would-be-bluestem-burger/) (Minnesota I think, although she has also lived in New York City):

> So even though I do appreciate a nice bit of crackling skin now and then, I had [the pig] “skunned” (as they say around here).
>   <sub>[Butchering a Pig in the Yard, Part Two](http://www.amythielen.com/butchering-a-pig-in-the-yard-part-two/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 results of your search for skun [Macquarie](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/skun/Tasmania/)

skun:  skinned:

> I skun my knee. They skun a few bunnies. Used in north eastern Tassie
>   50 years ago.

Aussies too. Keep them eyes skunned for more!